# Guess the winning button by clicking on one of them - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, buttonclick

You have 3 buttons. On of them, randomly chosen, is a winner. Display if the winning button has been clicked or not. Bonus: Generate n buttons, from which one of them is winner.

My code so far:

```
let n = 3, buton
for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    buton = document.createElement("button")
    document.querySelector("body").appendChild(buton)
    buton.id = i
    buton.innerText = i
}
let winningButton = 1 // Math.floor(Math.random() * n)
let onClick = function() {
    if (winningButton == buton.id) {
        alert("Congratulations! You've guessed the button!")
    }
}
buton.addEventListener("click", onClick)
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: You're setting the `buton` variable in your loop. so when you click on the button it's just comparing the `winningbutton` number to the id of the last button that was created. Since 1 will never equal 3, it fails every time. You need to pass the event to the function, then compare the winningButton number to the button that was actually pressed.

Comment: To test that, set your `winningButton` to equal 3, then test. You should succeed every time.

Answer (score 1):

In the onClick function, you are not checking against the clicked button, you can use the `this` keyword to access the button in the event handler

```
let onClick = function() {
    if (winningButton == this.id) {
        alert("Congratulations! You've guessed the button!")
    }
}
```

If you use arrow functions `this` will not be work, so instead, you can use the event object to get the target element

```
let onClick = (event) => {
    if (winningButton == event.target.id) {
        alert("Congratulations! You've guessed the button!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a random number when the user clicks.

```js
let n = 3;
let winningButton;
const onClick = function() {
  winningButton = winningButton ? winningButton : Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
  if (winningButton == this.id) {
    alert("Congratulations! You've guessed the button!")
  }
}
for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  const buton = document.createElement("button")
  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(buton)
  buton.id = i
  buton.innerText = i;
  buton.addEventListener("click", onClick);
}
```